# how to allow user manual entry in datagridview combobox in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to enter values in a datagridview Combobox. but it does not Allows. What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```cs
private void GridStockItemEntry_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewRow row = GridStockItemEntry.CurrentRow;
        DataGridViewCell cell = GridStockItemEntry.CurrentCell;
        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
        {

            if (cell == row.Cells["ItemName"] && Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Type"].Value) == "Raw Material")
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cbo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;

                cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

                cbo.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(cbo_Validating);
            }
        }


    }
    void cbo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cbo = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;

        DataGridView grid = cbo.EditingControlDataGridView;

        object value = cbo.Text;

        // Add value to list if not there

        if (cbo.Items.IndexOf(value) == -1)
        {

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboCol = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)grid.CurrentCell;

            // Must add to both the current combobox as well as the template, to avoid duplicate entries...

            cbo.Items.Add(value);

            cboCol.Items.Add(value);

            grid.CurrentCell.Value = value;

        }

    }
```

Comment: cbo_validating() is called continuously even when i am setting e.cancel as true. is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, this example is better readable:

```
private void datagridview_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        if(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==dgv.Columns["ColumnName"].Index) {
            ComboBox cbx = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            cbx.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            cbx.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            cbx.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that `EditMode` property of the `DataGridView` is set to `EditOnKeystrokeOrF2`

Also, verify that `ReadOnly` property is set to `False`.

Comment: it doesnot allow for combobox

Comment: What doesn't allow for combobox? I just tried a gridview with these properties AND a combobox in a column.

Comment: this options will not work  datagridview. as per your answer it will be only allow to select value from combobox, it will not allow to enter text