# How to reproduce the behaviour of a real ComboBox in when using a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

Topic Introduction:

> I recently noticed, that when you use the DataGridViewColumn-Class to
>   create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn inside of a DataGridView this
>   "ComboBox" will behave differently from a familiar ComboBox behaviour
>   of a ComboBos created with the System.Windows.Forms.Control-Class.
>
> When you click a traditional ComboBox, a DropDownMenu opens, this also
>   works with the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn-ComboBos but seems a little
>   bit delayed.
>
> When you double-click a traditional ComboBox you can enter your own
>   text and when you press enter afterwards this own text will display in
>   the ComboBox instead of a selected text out of the pre-determined
>   texts inside the DropDownMenu of the ComboBox.

To come to my specific problem:

> When I use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn-ComboBox and double click on
>   it I will not have the abiity to create a own text, the ComboBox will
>   display afterwards.

What I did:

> I tried to search for this problem in the internet using different
>   words for describing both the problem and/or a possible solution but I
>   did not find the exact same problem. Most of the threads had questions
>   like "How to use a ComboBox inside a DataGridView" and the answers
>   varied from "Use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" to "Draw your own
>   ComboBox using the ComboBoxRenderer-Class". I found lots of code
>   examples but NONE had the ability to do what I described above".

What I hope for:

> If you have or had experience with this kind of problem or even the
>   specific problem I mentioned, it would be very helpfull if you could
>   share your thoughtprocess about the problem no matter you solved the
>   problem or not. Any thoughts and ideas could guide me to a solution.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow user manual entry in datagridview combobox? Let a user add an item not already in the combobox list?

Comment: @ Kinyanjui Kamau Exactly.

Comment: Okay, I found a solution which has to do with creating a own DataGridView-type containing a regular ComboBox and then using that type inside of a specific DataGridViewColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968266/how-to-allow-user-manual-entry-in-datagridview-combobox-in-c-sharp). Follow the code that will let you add a new value to list if it is not there.

Ensure that the EditMode property of the DataGridView is set to `EditOnKeystrokeOrF2` and
`ReadOnly` property is set to False.

Comment: Thank you ! Will try this solution and check if the functionality acts like the ComboBox-behaviour I'm used to.