# Value for DataGridViewComboBox clears when focused

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have implemented a `DataGridViewComboBox` that allows editing using the code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968266/how-to-allow-user-manual-entry-in-datagridview-combobox-in-c-sharp).

My problem right now is that when I focus the cell, the value is cleared. Based on the posts I've read, the item must be added to the combobox first. So here's what I have tried. Can you possibly tell me what's going wrong?

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;

            if (cell == row.Cells[colComboBox.Name])
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl control = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                control.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

                //For testing purposes
                colComboBox.Items.Add("Test");//I'm adding the item to the combobox control
                row.Cells[colComboBox.Name].Value = "Test";//Then set the value of the cell based on the item I added
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == colComboBox.Index)
        {
            colComboBox.Items.Clear();
            object eFV = e.FormattedValue;
            if (!colComboBox.Items.Contains(eFV))
            {
                colComboBox.Items.Add(eFV);
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = eFV;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Upvoted for good title

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked, the `Validating` event used is the editing combo box one and not the `DataGridView`'s `CellValidating` one.

By the way, using the `EditingControlShowing` event to access the editing control is generally a bad idea. I would suggest you to use a cell template by adding this code before populating your datagridview :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell templateCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
templateCell.Items.Add("Test");
templateCell.Items.Add("Test2");
colComboBox.CellTemplate = templateCell;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out that I'm using the DataGridView's event. More or less I get the same result, just that other cells are affected too. Anyway, I think using the EditingControlShowing event is necessary as that's where I have to transform the combobox's style. Specifically, the effect I really want is that of a textbox control, where when you focus the textbox, the contents are highlighted and not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why the `DataGridViewComboBox` behaves this way. But experimenting on to the `ComboBox` control with default properties, it does not clear the value when focused and behaves just like a `TextBox` control. The solution is just to actually set the `Text` property of the control to a e.g. global variable of some sort that can be accessed by other events bound to the control. As for now this is the behaviour that I'm trying to achieve.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl control = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        control.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        control.Text = SomeGlobalVariable;
```